# Update variable at condition

Tags: pine-script-v5

I would like to update a variable (in the below example is `new_profit_long`) every time a condition is verified.

The following is a simplified example of what I want to achieve:

```
entry = nz(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1))
profit = entry + tp
loss = entry - sl
extra = tp * .5
new_profit = profit

if close > profit
    if close > new_profit
        new_profit := new_profit + extra
    else
        strategy.close("long")
else if close < loss
    strategy.close("long")
```

Unfortunately, I get this behaviour:

| close | entry | (old) new_profit | (new) new_profit | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 782.7 | 783.5 | 783.5 | 783.5 | enter |
| 784.0 |  | 783.5 | 784.5 | `new_profit` changed |
| 784.6 |  | 783.5 | 784.5 | `new_profit` not changed: why? |
| 781.4 |  | 783.5 | 783.5 |  |
| 776.9 |  | 783.5 | 783.5 | exit |

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with this solution:

```
entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
profit = entry + tp
loss = entry - sl
extra = tp * .5

var float new_profit = na
var float old_profit = na

if not new_profit
    new_profit := profit

if close > profit
    if close > new_profit
        old_profit := new_profit
        new_profit := new_profit + extra
    else if close < old_profit
        strategy.close("long")
        new_profit := na
        old_profit := na
else if close < loss
    strategy.close("long")
    new_profit := na
    old_profit := na
```